# Repeated measures on social work data with binary or 3-rank outcomes, in SPSS

Tags: repeated-measures, ordinal-data, ranking

I am helping an agency that serves vulnerable populations, and wants to know if their methods and outcomes differ between subpopulations served. I am only familiar with and have access to SPSS. My previous experience was primarily with scale-based surveys in social psychology, so mostly multiple-regression based methods. They do not apply here, and I am trying to figure out what I know, what I don’t know, and how to best catch up. So I would very much appreciate feedback on the thoughts below.

Also, I have read this community before but never contributed to it. But then, I am not sure I have enough experience and knowledge to meaningfully answer somebody else’s questions, as my previous research was limited to grad student experience only.

This is a repeated measures analysis over 8-10 time points where my IVs are all categorical — things like subpopulations and gender.

My DVs/outcomes are a whole bunch of ordinal data, that’s either binary (yes/no; success/failure) or has 3 ranks (success, partial success, failure).

I am also realizing that there are entirely too many DVs for the sample size. I was talking to the agency about meaningful ways to collapse some of them: For example, if several questions ask about housing stability, I could collapse them into a single rank measure, rather then analyze them as 2-3 separate DVs. Does this sound sensible?

Fortunately, the research questions are historical. I am not trying to predict or extrapolate things for other populations - I am only trying to understand outcomes for this specific sample of clients.

I believe that SPSS basic Repeated Measures test does not apply here. I have been reading on Friedman’s test for correlated samples, which I believe I can use. I am also wondering about ordinal logistic regression for repeated measures - is that also appropriate? Are there non paywall-ed articles I can read on the subject? I believe I should be able to figure out the relevant syntax on my own, but I would not turn down a quick syntax suggestion either... I did a keyword search and I am checking relevant threads here and other articles that pop up, but I figured it doesn’t hurt to ask the specific questions anyway.

Thank you for your time, whomever chooses to read this.